# How many times a TypeScript file compiles?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, mean-stack

I want to study `typescript` and start to build my idea by using **MEAN** technology stack but I am afraid that `typescript` needs to be run every time a user enters the website or it is only one time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You build your project once using the TypeScript compiler and that produces .js files that can be run directly in nodejs or the browser (depending upon which environment they were designed for).

This is one-time process.  From then on, the only code that actually "runs" is the compiled output .js files.

So, NO TypeScript code does not need to be re-compiled every time a user enters a web-site.

Your code would typically be recompiled only when you modify it and wish to "build" the newer version of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript compiles to JavaScript when you run the `ng build` and it also optimizes codes. After build completes you will have an `index.html` plus `.js` files that each one is generated based on one of your lazy loaded modules.